# Python letting me access Protected instance attributes outside of class

Tags: python, protected

In this Python program, I created an Employee class which has a protected instance attribute, '_id'. It is my understanding that in Python, to create a protected attribute, you start the name with a single underscore. However, it is allowing me to access this protected attribute outside of the class. The output of this program is:
12345

Why is it doing this?

```
class Employee:

    def __init__(self, full_name, ID = 0):
        self._firstname, self._lastname = full_name.split(" ")
        self._id =  ID

    @property
    def firstname(self):
        return self._firstname
    
    @property
    def id(self):
        return self._id
    
    @firstname.setter
    def firstname(self, new):
        self._firstname = new
    
    @id.setter
    def id(self, new):
        self._id = new

    @firstname.deleter
    def firstname(self):
        self._firstname = None
    
    @id.deleter
    def id(self):
        _id = None



bob = Employee("Billy Bob", 12345)

print(bob._id)
```

Comment: Python **does not have access modifiers**. There is **no access control**.

Comment: I thought there were? I don't know if I'm missing something, but there's many youtube videos about it, and resources online that say there's access modifiers. If i put a __ prefix instead, it becomes "private", and if I try to access the attribute, it gives me an attribute error.

Comment: There are a lot of wrong videos on Youtube. (Also, `__` isn't private - it activates name mangling. You can still access the attributes just fine, but it's harder to do so by accident.)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. I understand now that the underscores are simply convention. I was confused to thinking that access modifiers existed because when I used the convention for a private attribute, '__', it wouldn't let me access the attribute externally. The reason it wouldn't let me access it was because of name mangling.